# Trying to implement nebula project is throwing an error: The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression

Tags: npm, qlikview, qliksense, nebula, mashup

I am following the instructions on this page:
https://qlik.dev/tutorials/build-a-chatbot-using-the-qlik-sense-natural-language-api

I am actually getting an error which says the following:

```
    At line:1 char:5
npx @nebula.js/cli create mashup hello-saas
+     ~~~~~~~
The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expression. '@nebula' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference variables in an expression use '$nebula'.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

Answer (score 2):

This because you are running the command in `PowerShell`. You cant use `@` so easily there.

Two options:

- run the command in `cmd`
- or, in `PowerShell`, wrap the `@` command in quotes. like this: `npx "@nebula.js/cli" create mashup hello-saas`